# Memory efficiency of three properties compared to one NSDictionary

Tags: performance, cocoa, declared-property

I want to pass some data to my object and there are two options for me.

Regarding memory - what's more effecient? To declare three properties or to to declare one `NSDictionary` using `initWithCapacity:3`?

Comment: If you go saving BOOLs in dictionary then this is surely a bad way. For effieciency 3 properties will be better. readable.

Comment: I'm not going to store primitives but my own objects. Properties are still better, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring 3 properties will use less memory and be more performant than using an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Using properties also makes your code easier to read and allows your compiler to help you with type-safety.

Another consideration, is that you can't store `nil` in a collection.

EDIT:

As far as memory is concerned, the only difference between the 2 options that you mentioned is that the `NSDictionary` requires its own memory in the heap.  The objects themselves will still require the same memory in the heap either way.

Comment: Can you provide some evidence for your performance assertion?

Comment: In a property, the memory address of the object is stored in the backing `ivar`.  In a `NSDictionary` a hash-table lookup has to be done to get the address of the object.

Comment: There's a secondary lookup for ivars, too: http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/01/27/objc_explain_Non-fragile_ivars.html. I don't necessarily disagree, but can you provide some _evidence_ for your performance assertion?

Comment: You have to do that lookup anyway to get ahold of the `NSDictionary`, so that gives you 2 lookups instead of just one for an ivar in a property.

Answer (score 2):

I would advocate for using properties, but not because of a performance issue; simply because I think it's more readable and less error-prone—you can make the dictionary approach clean by using key constants, but it's extra work.

The bottom line here, for me, is that until Instruments shows you that you're spending a significant amount of time or memory on these objects, you should take the path of readability and clarity.  It's highly unlikely that it's going to matter if you shave a few cycles or a few bytes.  But even if it does, it's not going to be a huge job to refactor the approach you take for an object initialization of three parameters.